# how to make a bar rating system using logarithm

Tags: jquery, css, rating, voting, voting-system

I want to make a bar rating system for my website and this is what i have actually:

[image]

Which doesn't look nice at all :p. I want the height to increase like a Exponential curve gradually. Not too steep at the beginning, which gradually increase afterward.

Using:

```
height = (Math.ceil( Math.log(i) * 10) / 10 ) + settings.height
```

where **i** is the for loop variable from 0 -> 19(number of bars) and settings.height being the base height which is 15. 
What should i do to correct it?

edit: Like this but upside down
[image]

Comment: what do you mean with base height?

Comment: it will start at that height, then gradually increase

Comment: this is linear http://jsfiddle.net/m3L3k/

Comment: can't add some curve increase to it a little?

Comment: a logarithmic increase "upside down" as you put it would just be an exponential increase

Comment: ahh..okay..sorry for that

Comment: what about this? http://jsfiddle.net/m3L3k/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is based on David Fregoli's initial comment which I expanded to get the wanted shape and correct orientation. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3L3k/3/) (Not intended to steal his answer, so feel free to accept his)

[image: The result]

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
}

bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #aaf;
    background-color: #ddf;
    margin-right: 1px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
var baseheight = 5;
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var h = 5*Math.pow(2,i/2) + baseheight;
    var offset = Math.ceil(150-h);
    $('#container').append($('<bar>').css('height', h).css('top', offset));
}
```

Comment: Thought was david Fregoli. it he don't post an anwser.i'll accept urs :)

Comment: no worries I don't know what I actually did so I was refreshing my maths, you can accept this one :D

Comment: can't it be les steep at first and more steep around 3/4 of it?

Comment: :p. i could but don't know why i prefer to use an algorithmn :p

Comment: the steepness can be controlled by the divisor in `Math.pow(2, i/2)` if you increase the divisor the steepness will diminish